# How to effectively perform complex processing on records read from a database

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, parallel-processing

fair warning: This is a question on approach and at least good-practice... The problem here is not syntax, but rather approach.

I'm having to process a huge volume of records very quickly and provide a transformed set of records to a consumer. I'm wondering if anyone has practical suggestions for the most effective way to do this.

Here is the scenario:

I need to perform a relatively simple set of logic:
Connect to DB -> Read records -> Transform each record -> provide output records to a consumer

This logic needs to be available from a library - with the internal logic entirely hidden from the consumer. (The consumer has no idea that some sort of transform happens - he thinks that he is just looping through a bunch of objects).

Normally, I would create an IEnumerable class with a a method like this:

```
public class TransformingReader<T> where T:class,new()
{
...
...
...

 public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
 {
      var items = _connection<dynamic>.GetData();
      foreach (var item in items)
      {
          T transformed = _complexTask.Transform(item);
          yield return transformed;
      }
 }
}
```

(use of dynamic class here is just for illustration)

Using the above class, the consumer:

```
foreach(var item in new TransformingReader<TransactionAnalysis>())
{
    ...
    DoStuff(item);
    ...
}
```

Facts:

1. I'm processing millions of records per day - so volume is a big issue.
2. The users DoStuff() function will take some time to complete. I have no real way to predict how complex their work will be, but it is bound to be more IO intensive that my work.
3. I'm working in a relatively constrained environment - so not huge amounts of memory available and other applications are on the same machine. So, I need to behave responsibly. (I'm not running on grandpa's laptop - but I still need to write sensible code that isn't greedy)

Thoughts:

1. I want to try to parallelize the Transform() function, so that I can use the time that DoStuff() is busy to transform the next records. In this way, hopefully, I'll always (often?) be ready with a new record by the time that the user asks for the next one.
2. I would love to keep the simple foreach-syntax on the consumers side. No need for the consumer to know that I'm working hard behind the scenes.

Any ideas on how to solve this type of issue would really be appreciated. Specifically, is there maybe a pattern that I'm not aware of that could help solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a producer-consumer pattern.

See [Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff963548(v=pandp.10)) how you can implement it.

```
var records = new BlockingCollection<SomeRecord>();
var outputs = new BlockingCollection<SomeResult>();

var readRecords = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var record = new SomeRecord { Prop = reader.GetValue(0) };
                records.Add(record);
            }
        }
    }
});

var transformRecords = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var record in records.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // transform record
        outputs.Add(new SomeResult());
    }
});

var consumeResults = Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var result in outputs.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // ...
    }
});

Task.WaitAll(readRecords, transformRecords, consumeResults);
```

If necessary, the number of pipeline stages can be easily increased, adding new tasks.

Transformation is easy to parallelize:

```
records.GetConsumingEnumerable()
       .AsParallel()
       .AsOrdered() // if you want to keep order
```

If one of the tasks is much faster than the others and clogs memory, you can limit the capacity of its collection:

```
var records = new BlockingCollection<SomeRecord>(boundedCapacity: 50);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, brilliant - thanks @Alexander Petrov. The explanation that MadKarel gave, provided the context to understanding the basics even better. Such a shame that you can only select one answer!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [Produce-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

One solution would be to create a thread for retrieving and transforming data, the **producer thread**. Then in some other thread (could be the main thread) you run the **consumer**, the users `DoStuff(item)`. There would be a queue (most likely [concurrent queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)) that would be used to communicate between the threads.

From users viewpoint, you could still provide data as an enumerator, which would read from the queue, block when the queue is empty and end when it reads some predetermined value that signals the end of input (sometimes called *poison pill*).

Memory footprint is given by the size of the queue, so you can tailor it to your needs.

This pattern allows you to scale up the number of producers and consumers, so you could possibly `Transform()` multiple items at the same time and in parallel `DoStuff()` with multiple items at the same time.

From your description it may be possible to solve your problem with one [Parallel LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) statement (Which behind the scenes uses a variation of the solution described above).

Comment: Thanks @MadKarel. Such a shame you can only pick one answer. This gave me the background to understand Alexanders answer even better.